# Form field showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

This mostly works. It shows the SSN when the first Val radio button is picked. It also shows the PaperAppliction when the second Val radio button is picked.  The ONLY problem is that the field PaperApplication shows when the form is loaded before any radio buttons are picked.  I need it to hide both SSN and PaperApplicaition until one of the radio buttons is picked, and then show the proper field. What am I missing?

Here is the JS

```js
    $(".field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
      if (
        $(this).val() ==
        "As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number."
      ) {
        $(".field.SSN").show();
        $(".field.SSN input").focus();
        $(".field.PaperApplication").hide();
      } else if (
        $(this).val() ==
        "Due to my international student status, my residency status, or my specific visa type, I do not have a Social Security Number."
      ) {
        $(".field.PaperApplication").show();
        $(".field.PaperApplication input").focus();
        $("field.SSN").hide();
      } else {
        $("field.PaperApplication").hide();
      }
    });
```

Here is the form html
      
        US Citizen International Student Other

```
  <div class="field SSN">
    <label>SSN</label>
    <input />
  </div>

  <div class="field PaperApplication">
    <label>Paper Application</label>
    <input />
  </div>
```

Comment: I really wouldn't hardcode all that text e.g. `As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.` into the JavaScript code. Sure, display that text to the user next to the radio button, but don't use it as the _value_ of the radio button. Use something which refers to it, e.g. an numeric ID or a code or something. Something which is unique, and doesn't change. Because if that official wording changes in future, you don't want to have to update and re-test your code, you just want to be able to change some text in the page and be done with it

Comment: So you'd have something like `<label>
  really wouldn't hardcode all that text e.g. As a U.S. Citizen, permanent resident, or temporary working resident, I have a Social Security Number.
    <input type="radio" name="socialSecurityStatus" value="1" /> 
    </label>` and then in the JS you'd just write `$(this).val() == 1` - much simpler, more readable and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set them hidden initially using HTML markup to add a style attribute to the element. `style="display:none"` should do it.

e.g. `<div class="field SSN" style="display:none;">` and  the same for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Hide them both when the script is called, and also outside of the if statements when the change event is fired. Also, make your radio button values a word or two, camelCased. Put the string describing the button in the label tag:

```js
$(".SSN, .PaperApplication").hide();

$(".field.SocialSecurity input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  $(".SSN, .PaperApplication").hide();
  if ($(this).val() == "first") {
    $(".field.SSN").show();
    $(".field.SSN input").focus();
  } else if ($(this).val() == "second") {
    $(".field.PaperApplication").show();
    $(".field.PaperApplication input").focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field SocialSecurity">
  <label>
 Radio 1 text here
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="first" /> 
    </label><br>
  <label>
Radio 2 text here
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="second" />
    </label>
</div>

<div class="field SSN">
  <label>SSN</label>
  <input />
</div>

<div class="field PaperApplication">
  <label>Paper Application</label>
  <input />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hide on load, then on click hide both and show the one that was clicked. run below snippet

```js
$("input[name='socialsecurity']").click(() => {
   $('.field').hide();
  $(`.${$("input[name='socialsecurity']:checked").val()}`).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="socialsecurity" value="SSN"> SSN<br>
<input type="radio" name="socialsecurity" value="PaperApplication"> Paper Application<br>

 
 <div class="field SSN" style = 'display: none;'>
    <label>SSN</label>
    <input />
  </div>

  <div class="field PaperApplication" style = 'display: none;'>
    <label>Paper Application</label>
    <input />
  </div>
```